# Running bash script gives infinite y

Tags: shell

I was trying to fix my usb pen drive in Ubuntu so I ran the dosfsck command tocheck and repair MS-DOS filesystems because the filesystem of USB pen drive is vfat. While it was running, I accidentally closed the terminal. Now I am not able to run any bash script. When I enter ./script.sh (I have permissions for the script) I get inifinite 'y' messages. Please help :(

Thanks, Sou

Comment: Rebooting hasn't helped ? There is no reason I can see formatting an external drive would break bash interpreter. Is it only bash or also sh or python scripts for instance?

Comment: And what is the content of the script?

Answer (score 0):

Actually command "yes" prints infinite "y" in bash. So you must have command "yes" called somewhere, probably in your .bashrc. Just check !